# Winform chart - Fixed X Axis

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to present a chart with new, live data, but I want the X Axis, and X grid lines, to stay fixed at some predetermined interval.  So, I'm constantly adding new points to the chart but I want the grid to stay constant.  Is there a way to override the X axis behavior this way?  Thanks.

Comment: They will stay once you set minimum and maximum values for the x-axis. Of course if you add points beyond that you won't see them.. Also:  Note that there are various interval properties including those for the major/minor gridlines.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  However, I will be adding points for the life of the chart and I want the points to compress (in the X direction) as they normally would when the chart fills up.  What I want is the X axis tick marks and grid lines to stay fixed as I add the new data.

Comment: But how could they?? The data compress so the ticks etc go wih them. They are related to the values. If you want to break that, why have them in the first place??

Comment: I understand that's the behavior, is there a way to override it?  I am adding a fixed set of custom labels and I want the tick marks and grid lines to match up with my labels.

Comment: Well you could adapt the Intervals of those element to the growing number of points they have to cover. Curious: How did you 'fix' the CustomLabels? They ought to be bound to the axis values as well via their to- & FromValues.

Comment: That's true.  I actually hid the chart X axis labels and drew my own where I wanted them.